# CoreData One-to-One Relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

In my app, Im using CoreData and I have two entities. VenueInfo and ContactInfo.

In the app, you can add venues, and each venue has ContactInfo. So I've setup a one to one relationship in my model.

So I would imagine, I could simply do the following:

`[venue.contact setValue:textField.text forKey:email];`

So like so you'd set the email attribute of the contact object which belongs to the venue. However this doesn't work.

Is it possible because the contact object doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your .xcodeModel...

Comment: I updated my answer. Please have a look..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line you wrote won't work that way. I assume contact is the relationship name you have in your Venue entity in xCodeModel.

```
 [venue.contact setValue:textField.text forKey:email]; // can't write this way..
```

Suppose your `ContactInfo` entity has two fields : `phone`, `email` so this way you can go.
        and  `VenueInfo`   entity has two fields :  `name`.

```
  VenueInfo *venueInfo=[NSEntityDescription   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"VenueInfo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
  vanueInfo.name=txtVenueName.text;           // venue name entry


  ContactInfo *contactInfo=[NSEntityDescription   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ContactInfo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

  contactInfo.phone=txtPhone.text;
  contactInfo.email=txtEmail.text;
  contactInfo.venue=venueInfo;  // I assume venue is the relationship name you give in ContactInfo entity towards Venue entity.
```

What we did here is we saved phone and email details to `ContactInfo` entity only and then we just related it with currently selected `VenueInfo` accessing the relationship we declared in `ContactInfo` Entity for `VenueInfo`.

This maybe quite confusing so I'll recommend you to follow a few tutorials which will give you an idea to grasp some basics about core data relationships.

Comment: changed contactInfo.venue=selectedVenue; to    contactInfo.venue=venueInfo;

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense, however surely this only works the first time you give the venue contact info? Because the next time you come back to edit this, your making a new contact object again, surely you need to access it existing info using something like venue.contact?

Comment: Sorry but not getting you? Did you refer any reference or sample codes for core data?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to access it again? Like edit it??

Comment: Yep, first time the user adds a venue, I will need to make a new contact object for that venue, right? But the user is allowed to edit the venue, so when they come back, rather than making a new contact object they need to access the preexisting one.

Comment: Do you mind if I get back to your query after some time? You can find me in chat room also.. That would be more convenient..